# (Carrito) estado de productos disponible/reservado/vendido ¿como mostrar el que corresponda?

Tags: php, html, mariadb

Estoy actualizando/revisando una tienda/web que hice hace tiempo con dreamweaver cs6, html5,php y mysql.
Me encuentro trabajando la página Products_edit.php de la carpeta de administración, desde ella edito los productos que voy añadiendo a la web/tienda, precio, descripción etc, y/o un select con 3 campos: Disponible, Reservado, Vendido, añado parte del código.

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tabla_productos SET strNombre=%s, strDescripcion=%s, strSEO=%s, dblPrecio=%s, intEstado=%s, intCategoria=%s, strImagen=%s WHERE idProductos=%s",
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['strNombre'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['strDescripcion'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['strSEO'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['dblPrecio'], "double"),
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['intEstado'], "int"),
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['intCategoria'], "int"),
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['strImagen'], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($link, $_POST['idProductos'], "int"));

mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db);
$Result1 = mysqli_query($link, $updateSQL) or die(mysqli_error());}

$varProductos_EditProductos = "0";
if (isset($_GET["recordID"])) {
$varProductos_EditProductos = $_GET["recordID"];
}
?>
```

Tras las consultas a la DB está el formulario con los campos a editar **Omito poner todos**

```
<form method="post" name="form1" class="user_box" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">

<tr valign="baseline">
<td nowrap align="right">Estado:</td>
<td><select name="intEstado">
<option value="1" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Disponible</option>
<option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Reservado</option>
<option value="3" <?php if (!(strcmp(3, ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Vendido</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

Todo esto funciona correctamente, no hay ningún problema pero lo adjunto para que ayude y focalice.

Lo que me pregunto y quisiera hacer es que cuando un usuario interactue con un producto desde su página Products.php (no confundir con la de  Productos_edit de arriba), este producto cambie su estado en la pagína Categories.php y Products.php, ya que están relacionadas.
**Código de Categorias.php**

```
<?php 
$varCategoria_DatosProductos = "0";
if (isset($_GET["categ"])) {
$varCategoria_DatosProductos = $_GET["categ"];
}
mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db);
$query_DatosProductos = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tabla_productos WHERE tabla_productos.intCategoria = %s",
GetSQLValueString($link, $varCategoria_DatosProductos, "int"));
$DatosProductos = mysqli_query($link,$query_DatosProductos) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_DatosProductos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosProductos);
$totalRows_DatosProductos = mysqli_num_rows($DatosProductos);
include("../includes/Elusuario.php"); ?>
<a href="Catalog.php">Catálogo</a>
<a href="#">Blog</a>

<?php if ((isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) && ($_SESSION['loggedin']!= "")){}
else{?>
<a href="../Clientes/Logueo.php" >Entrar </a></div>
<?php 
}?>
<?php do { ?>
<div class="productos">
<span class="boldlink">
<?php echo $row_DatosProductos['strNombre']; ?></span><br>
<a href="Products.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_DatosProductos['idProductos']; ?>">
<img src="../images/prettyPhoto/fotosserver/<?php echo $row_DatosProductos['strImagen']; ?>" width="175" ></a><br>      
<span class="boldlink">Price:</span><?php echo $row_DatosProductos['dblPrecio']; ?>€
**Destaco la siguiente línea row que es la que recoge los datos**

<span class="boldlink"> Estado:</span><?php echo $row_DatosProductos['intEstado']; ?></div>

<?php } while ($row_DatosProductos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosProductos)); 
mysqli_free_result($DatosProductos);
?>
```

A mi entender cuando se esta haciendo `$row_DatosProductos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosProductos);` se esta cogiendo ese estado de la DB y si se le imprime con un echo  lo normal y así sucede es que aparezca lo que almacena ese row de la DB.

A mi me almacena numeros "vease" 1,2,3 y normal que aprezcan, lo que yo quiero saber y entender es ¿para qué en el `<tr / td>` se han puesto (que yo no lo hice) las opciones del selector, Disponible, Reservado y Vendido? ¿No es para aprovecharlas despues y mostrarlas al usuario cuando este viendo la página productos? Ejemplo: veo un producto, se llama así, vale tanto, esta echo con, "pero que pena", esta reservado, o no esta vendido o no, esta disponible, esto es entendible espero. Pues bueno en el estado de la página Products.php imprime 1, 2, 3 ¿y eso al usuario ¿que le dice?

Termino, creo que esta bien planteada mi pregunta, no voy a editarla ni por sugerencias de ningún tipo, si un usuario no la entiende puede que otro sí, llevo 2 días hablando Swahili y ya dije de buenas maneras que no se, empaticen.

Comment: No se entiende del todo la pregunta, ¿podrías editar y explicar mejor por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que intentas seleccionar una opcion dependiendo el cual evalúas.
Yo intentaría la siguiente manera.

Primero hacemos el componente en html

```html
<select name="intEstado">
<option value="1" >Disponible</option>
<option value="2" >Reservado</option>
<option value="3" >Vendido</option>
</select>
```

Despues de tener el componente visual vamos a trabajar con la parte logica que es la que va hacer que nuestra aplicacion funcione.
En este caso tenemos varias opciones, hacer una condicion simple if o switch case cual sea de las dos funcionan igual.

```html
if (!(strcmp(1,""))) {
  echo "Disponible";
}
else if (!(strcmp(2,""))) {
  echo "Reservado";
}
else (!(strcmp(3,""))) {
  echo "Vendido";
}
```

O hacer el switch case

```html
switch ($datoAEvaluar) {
    case 1:
        echo "Disponible";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "Reservado";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "Vendido";
        break;
}
```

Ya que tenemos las dos partes es hora de combinarlos y hacer que lo hagan de manera visual en el componente de html.
Por lo regular se recomienda trabajar con javascript para el frontend pero eso no lo veremos en este ejemplo.
Entonces al en mi parecer quedaria asi.

```html
<select name="intEstado">
  <?php if (!(strcmp(1,""))) {
  ?>
  <option value="1" selected>Disponible</option>
      <?php
} else{
  ?>
  <option value="1" >Disponible</option>
      <?php
}
if (!(strcmp(2,""))) {
  ?>
  <option value="2" selected>Reservado</option>
      <?php
} else {
  ?>
  <option value="2" >Reservado</option>
      <?php
}
if (!(strcmp(3,""))) {
  ?>
  <option value="3" selected>Vendido</option>
      <?php
} else{
  ?>
  <option value="3" >Vendido</option>
      <?php
}

?>


</select>
```

El funcionamiento es el siguiente.
Si la condicion se cumple creame el componente con el atributo "selected" si no se cumple la condicion creame el componente sin ese atributo, eso para los 3 casos.
Igual este codigo se puede mejorar aplicandole varias cosas pero en si la parte funcional con la parte visual funciona. 
Espero esto te sirviera.

Comment: Hola @javiershaka, disculpa yo no se programar, es solo que tengo una web que hice y la estoy arreglando para usarla en un futuro. ¿Este código que pusiste donde iría; antes del otro, después, o lo sustituiría? He probado todo y no veo cambios, sigue mostrando el nº que haya en la DB, 1 para Disponible 2 para Reservado y 3 para vendido, yo quiero mostrar esos textos, no el número ¿Esto es posible? Quizá no se pueda. Saludos

Comment: No hay ningun problema, permiteme explicarte paso a paso para sea mas sencillo comprender la necesidad del problema. Primero necesitamos identificar la necesidad para resolver este problema, bien que necesitamos hacer ?, y cito tu explicacion de la siguiente manera "tengo que hacer una lista desplegable(select) cuando este en "x" estado por ejemplo es decir, que salga Reservado y no el nº2 que es lo que he logrado mostrar"  ya que tenemos eso sigue el siguiente paso(por lo personal primero) empiezo con lo funcional por lo que aqui(que es lo logico de tu aplicacion) en este caso las condiciones

Comment: Despues de hacer lo funcional nos pasamos al diseño, ahora tenemos lo funcional, ahora es apllicarlo a los componentes para que se muestren de una manera visual para el usuario, en este caso es donde tendremos que hacer la lista que teniamos en mente con anterioridad, (si vas empezando te recomendaria hacer el componente en puro html y despues meterle el php  asi sera mas facil identificar lo que hacemos) ya despues creado el componente toca hacer que funcione junto a nuestra parte logica que es la funcional.
Voy a modificar mi post para que sea mas facil de entender.

Comment: Gracias por tu dedicación @javiershaka, creo que estamos hablando de cosas distintas. En el select desplegable si me aparecen los estados como texto, es a la hora de mostrarlo en el front-end del producto cuando aparece el nº que es lo que recoge la DB. No sé si me sigues, creo que estamos en distintos términos. Probé de todas las maneras posibles recolocado tu código, escribiendo los valores a mano y nada, a la DB entran números, y es lo que muestra el `echo <?php` . Saludos

Comment: Dejame ver si comprendi en el select te aparece el nº que creo por lo que dices es tu Primary Key de tu tabal de la base de datos. 
Podrias dar mas info?
sobre que dato quieres que se muestre, resultados (de preferencia imagen) , etc.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, te explico brevemente y mañana seré más conciso que hoy estoy cansado mentalmente. Lo que estoy haciendo es manejar una tr que me edita los campos de un producto de mi carrito, el producto ya está subido claro y por ejemplo quiero rebajarle el precio, pues entro a productos_edit y edito ese campo precio. Bien, como imaginamos hay más campos, nombre, categoría etc, entre ellas el selector para estado, disponible reservado etc. Cuando edito ahí y guardo, refresco mi página productos y aparecen números, no palabras (Reservado, vendido etc. Mañana edito el post con detalle.

Comment: Creo que ya entendí, los select devuelven el el valor (value) que seleccionas, en lugar de ponerle los números ponle las palabras(en lugar de 1,2,3 en el value pon las palabras Dispoble, Reservado , vendido ), deja la validación como la tienes e intentarlo)

Comment: Buenos días, he editado arriba la pregunta y añadido mas código he información, ya comente ayer que incluso poniendo los valores a mano no aparecen los textos en el fron-ent de la pagina productos del clientes, aparecen numeros. Arriba está explicado, marcho que tengo cosas que hacer, gracias por la dedicación.

Comment: *Lo solucioné* no sigan ya está, no sé por qué quién hizo el tutorial le daba valor integer, menos mal no pagué por el cursillo, lo puse varchar, corregi todos los códigos y funciona.